# I cant log in. What do i do?

Tags: xubuntu

So I deleted xubuntu, I rebooted my pc and it asks for my login then my password.

And if I type my password in the login it wont work.

(xubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Installing a new OS, in place of the deleted one, would be a good idea.

Comment: What exactly did you delete, and where are you trying to login? Kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console.